# Optimizing PowerBI query for creating a "to date" maximum

Tags: dataframe, powerbi

I have a time series data set that is almost monotone increasing.  The values of the series will dip every now and then, but it generally increases.  The dips that occur in the series are due to errors in a sensor reading either previous values being to high or later values being to low.  My goal is to apply a pre-processing transformation to get a more stable signal.  Here is an image for reference:

[Pre-prossesing vs raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU3ZH.png)

I can do this relatively easily in python, but I'm having a difficult time doing this efficiently in Power BI.  Here is an example table of raw and processed data to give an example of what I'm hoping to do:

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i21nQ.png)

Here is the DAX code that I've to apply to create the ProcessedValue Column:

```
ProcessedValue = 
VAR CurrentIndex = Query1[Index]
RETURN
Calculate (
     MAX ( Query1[Value] ),
     FILTER (
          ALL ( Query1 ),
          Query1[Index] < CurrentIndex
          && Query1[Index] > CurrentIndex - 50
     )
)
```

The two issues that I'm running into are 1) I run out of memory and 2) I don't know if the code is even doing what I'm intending it to do (because it doesn't complete).  The table has ~ 1M data points.  I'm fairly new to Power BI and I'm not aware of the tips and tricks needed to do fast calculations, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  For reference here is the code that I'm using in python:

```
def backward_max(a, axis=0):
    bmax = np.array([np.max(a[: max(1, i)], axis=axis) for i in range(len(a))])
    return bmax

df['ProcessedValue'] = backward_max(df['Value'].values)
```

Comment: are you running the 32 bit or the 64 bit version of Power BI Desktop?

Comment: I'm running the 64 bit version

Comment: I tested the method above with a simpler data set, and it seems to do what I need.  The process runs out of memory when executing the code.  I've decided to do the heavy lifting in python, save the output to file/db, and then pull that info into Power BI.